# Passing data from a textarea to a function and routing

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to web development and have been learning Laravel. I am following a video tutorial series (https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch). In the series they use a text are to pass data to a post controller. I would like the user to input their name. If they are in the database, then they are taken to a user's page. I have the Model, database, and migrations working.

For the index page, routing:

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index');
Route::get('/user', UserController@checked');
Route::get('/accesdenied','UserController@accessdenied');
```

index view:

```
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h1>Please enter User Name</h1>
    <form>
       <div>
           <textarea name="body"></textarea> 
           <button type="submit">Access</button>
       </div>     
    </form>
```

controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('users.index');//view is in users folder
    }
    public function check(Request $request)
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', $request->body)->first();
        if (isset($user))
            return view(‘users.checked’, compact(‘user’));
        else
            return view('users.accessdenied');//is it right to direct to a page back to a controller?
    }   
    public function accessdenied(Request $request)
    {
        //try again is same as index page with text added
        return view('users.tryagain');
    }   
}
```

I have no idea what to pass from the form.

Thank you.

Comment: where your form action that hit the route?

Comment: from the index view, I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a small change

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h1>Please enter User Name</h1>
<form method="get" action="{{ action('UserController@checked') }}">
   <div>
       <textarea name="body"></textarea> 
       <button type="submit">Access</button>
   </div>     
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting an error at "Route::get('/user', UserController@checked');" "Unexpected @ at line..". The page exists in the right directory.

Comment: @rur2641 You are missing an opening single quote on `UserController@checked'`. Should be `'UserController@checked'`.

Comment: Thanks! It is working when I enter a name that is not on the database but when I enter a name that is I receive error  "Use of undefined constant ‘users - assumed '‘users' " for "return view(‘users.checked’, compact(‘user’));" .

Comment: i think some variable is not passing in view from controller